# What are the best options to host an ASP.NET website, Java Restful webservice , MySQL Db and Web Crawler written in C# on Windows Azure?

Tags: rest, azure

I'm a student and we (the team) are trying to host our graduation project on Azure. We mainly have five components which are :

1- A crawler that crawls data from website and it is written in C#

2- MySQL Database that store data crawled and the interactions of users in the ASP.NET website.

3- Java Restful web service that process the data collected and crawled and send results to the websites.

4- In addition , the ASP.NET website that view the data processed by the webservice in addition to other data from the db.

What are the best option to host all these components on Windows Azure ? Should we use Azure Cloud Services and Website Service or just a normal Virtual machines ?!

We don't have much knowledge about Cloud so please if you could also provide us with some resources that help us deploying all these components , we would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1- A crawler that crawls data from website and it is written in C#*

R:Worker Role (Cloud Services)

*2- MySQL Database that store data crawled and the interactions of users in the ASP.NET website.*

R:Virtual Machine / Clear DB (MySql from Azure Store)

*3- Java Restful web service that process the data collected and crawled and send results to the websites.*

R:If you chose Virtual Machine for item 2, you can use the same VM for that.

*4- In addition , the ASP.NET website that view the data processed by the webservice in addition to other data from the db.*

R:Azure Web Sites / Web Role (Cloud Services) / The same VM of item 2 and 3.

If it's a simple web site, go with WAMS (windows azure web sites), if you need more control, go with web role.

More info about execution models, it will clarify each one:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/